# Are there any exchanges like Shapeshift for testing and development?

Tags: testing, exchanges, bitcoin

I'm developing a simple application which involves calling Shapeshift, Bitfinex and similar exchange APIs.  They do not provide any sandboxed or under-testnet versions of their APIs for clients to use.

Do you know any similar 'fake' Exchange applications to be used for testing ETH/BTC nodes for development purposes?

Comment: please elaborate, is the application intending on making transactions? Or is it just collating data from these services.

Comment: Making transactions (conversions) between currencies.

Comment: You can pull price data from various sources like coinmarketcap then set up  nodes to transact to testnets on your behalf?

Comment: Yes, I do. I wanted to know if there was some available application already designed to do that.

Comment: @Hernán I am also using shapeshift api for conversion between cryptocurrency but they don't provide any testing API. Did you got any solution for this.